# Is there a solution to the integral equation $ H(y)=\int_0^\infty G(\frac{y-\phi_2(v)}{\phi_1(v)}) \exp(-v) ~\mathrm{d}v $?

Tags: integral-equations

Consider the following equation

$$
H(y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} G\left(\frac{y-\phi_2(v)}{\phi_1(v)} \right) \exp(-v) ~\mathrm{d}v
$$

where $\phi_i$ are well-behaved differentiable functions on the region of integration and G non-decreasing on the real line.

My question relates to whether there exists a family of solutions for $G$ written in terms of the function $H$ and if so what is its possible form?